# Excel Reference To Current Cell

Tags: excel, worksheet-function

How do I obtain a reference to the current cell?

For example, if I want to display the width of column A, I could use the following:

```
=CELL("width", A2)
```

However, I want the formula to be something like this:

```
=CELL("width", THIS_CELL)
```

Answer (score 53, accepted):

## Create a named formula called THIS_CELL

1. In the current worksheet, select cell A1 (this is important!)
2. Open `Name Manager` (Ctl+F3)
3. Click `New...`
4. Enter "THIS_CELL" (or just "THIS", which is my  preference) into `Name:`
5. Enter the following formula into `Refers to:`

   `=!A1`

   NOTE: *Be sure cell A1 is selected*. This formula is relative to the ActiveCell.
6. Under `Scope:` select `Workbook`.
7. Click `OK` and close the `Name Manager`

## Use the formula in the worksheet exactly as you wanted

```
=CELL("width",THIS_CELL)
```

**EDIT:** Better solution than using `INDIRECT()`

It's worth noting that the solution I've given should be preferred over any solution using the `INDIRECT()` function for two reasons:

1. It is nonvolatile, while `INDIRECT()` is a volatile Excel function, and as a result will dramatically slow down workbook calculation when it is used a lot.
2. It is much simpler, and does not require converting an address (in the form of `ROW()` `COLUMN()`) to a range reference to an address and back to a range reference again.

**EDIT:** Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22920090/excel-vba-worksheet-dependent-named-formula-named-range-result-changes-dependi) for more information on workbook-scoped, sheet dependent named ranges.

**EDIT:** Also see [@imix's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25291631/2437514) below for a variation on this idea (using RC style references). In that case, you could use `=!RC` for the `THIS_CELL` named range formula, or just use `RC` directly.

Comment: Great trick but I couldn't get it to work in Conditional Formulas (tested in Excel 2003 and 2016). The answer from @imix works.

Comment: @RickTeachy Yes, I mean inside formulas for conditional formatting.

Comment: @rkagerer iirc it works if the name is scoped to the sheet instead of the workbook. This is a bummer since it means you have to duplicate names across multiple sheets sometimes, but it does work. Will try to remember to confirm later.

Comment: @RicksupportsMonica re your assertion that `CELL` is nott volatile, it actuall _is_ [See this](https://www.decisionmodels.com/calcsecretsi.htm)

Comment: @chrisneilsen Thank you for pointing this out! The CELL() formula was just an example of how to use this feature... the THIS_CELL feature itself I describe is not volatile. I should find a different nonvolatile example though. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 56):

Several years too late:

Just for completeness I want to give yet another answer:

First, go to *Excel-Options* -> *Formulas* and enable *R1C1 references*.  Then use

```
  =CELL("width", RC)
```

`RC` always refers the current Row, current Column, i.e. "this cell".

[Rick Teachey's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22264393/2437514) is basically a tweak to make the same possible in *A1 reference style* (see also [GSerg's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/757413/excel-reference-to-current-cell/25291631#comment569235_757420) to Joey's answer and note [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/757413/excel-reference-to-current-cell/25291631#comment569230_757446) to Patrick McDonald's answer).

Cheers
:-)

Comment: Btw. the width actually only depends on the current column and can also be asked for with `=CELL("width", C)` where `C` is basically the "current column" (as `R` is the "current row").

Comment: This is great! Love it. You, my friend, get a bounty.

Comment: Wow, many thanks, Rick!  Now I can write comments everywhere and I can edit Community Wikis.  That's really great and a lot more freedom for me on SO.  I will use the Force wisely 8-)

Comment: I wasn't sure how portable this would be since you need to change a global setting. But it turns out the R1C1 option is also saved with the workbook, so it still works if someone else with default settings opens your file. Note if they switch the option off, Excel will convert all those RC's to normal references. At least that's what I inferred from a couple quick tests. Would appreciate if someone can corroborate this behavior.

Comment: @rkagerer: Note GSergs comment to Joeys answer. Internally, Excel works always with R1C1 style references so the option only allows the user to see and enter them also. It will still work after switching the option back to A1 reference style, just that you can't enter "RC" anymore and instead of RC the formulas show the (always changing) names of the cells they are in instead of the "constant" RC.

Answer (score 41):

You could use

```
=CELL("width", INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(), COLUMN())))
```

Comment: This makes the formula volatile. Therefore, provided there are non-volatile solutions, don't use this one.

Comment: It should probably be noted that the CELL function is already volatile, so whether or not the method you use to calculate the current cell is volatile will not affect the volatility of the function (in this case)

Comment: what does volatile mean?

Comment: @Jonathan There's an explanation here: http://www.decisionmodels.com/calcsecretsi.htm

Answer (score 32):

`=ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN(),4)`  will give us the relative address of the current cell. 
`=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN()-1,4))` will give us the contents of the cell left of the current cell
`=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW()-1,COLUMN(),4))` will give us the contents of the cell above the current cell (great for calculating running totals)

Using **CELL()** function returns information about the last cell that was changed. So, if we enter a new row or column the **CELL()** reference will be affected and will not be the current cell's any longer.

Comment: Thanks for this. In twenty years I've never knowingly used ADDRESS but when you have six columns, each with 500 rows that need a range-based conditional format replaced, it does speed things up somewhat, compared to having to redo every single one.

Answer (score 8):

`A2` is already a relative reference and will change when you move the cell or copy the formula.

Comment: Don't worry about addressing style. All formulas use R1C1 internally anyway, it doesn't matter.

Comment: Ah, thanks. Didn't bother to look it up right now (wading through the XML isn't exactly fun usually :))

Answer (score 8):

```
=ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN())
=ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN(),1)
=ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN(),2)
=ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN(),3)
=ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN(),4)
```

Answer (score 6):

Without INDIRECT(): `=CELL("width", OFFSET($A$1,ROW()-1,COLUMN()-1) )`

Answer (score 2):

I found the best way to handle this (for me) is to use the following:

```
Dim MyString as String
MyString = Application.ThisCell.Address
Range(MyString).Select
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Inside tables you can use `[@]` which (unfortunately) Excel automatically expands to `Table1[@]` but it does work. (I'm using Excel 2010)

For example when having two columns `[Change]` and `[Balance]`, putting this in the `[Balance]` column:

```
=OFFSET([@], -1, 0) + [Change]
```

Note of course that this depends on the order of the rows (just like most any other solution), so it's a bit fragile.

Answer (score 1):

There is a better way that is safer and will not slow down your application. How Excel is set up, a cell can have either a value or a formula; the formula can not refer to its own cell. You end up with an infinite loop, since the new value would cause another calculation... . Use a helper column to calculate the value based on what you put in the other cell. For Example:

Column A is a True or False, Column B contains a monetary value, Column C contains the folowing formula: 
=B1

Now, to calculate that column B will be highlighted yellow in a conditional format only if Column A is True and Column B is greater than Zero...

=AND(A1=True,C1>0)

You can then choose to hide column C

Answer (score 1):

Full credit to the top answer by @rick-teachey, but you can extend that approach to work with Conditional Formatting.  So that this answer is complete, I will duplicate Rick's answer in summary form and then extend it:

1. Select cell `A1` in any worksheet.
2. Create a Named Range called `THIS` and set the `Refers to:` to `=!A1`.

Attempting to use `THIS` in Conditional Formatting formulas will result in the error:

```
You may not use references to other workbooks for Conditional Formatting criteria
```

If you want `THIS` to work in Conditional Formatting formulas:

3. Create another Named Range called `THIS_CF` and set the `Refers to:` to `=THIS`.

You can now use `THIS_CF` to refer to the current cell in Conditional Formatting formulas.

You can also use this approach to create other relative Named Ranges, such as `THIS_COLUMN`, `THIS_ROW`, `ROW_ABOVE`, `COLUMN_LEFT`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: the following is wrong, because Cell("width") returns the width of the *last modified cell*.

`Cell("width")` returns the width of the current cell, so you don't need a reference to the current cell. If you need one, though, `cell("address")` returns the address of the current cell, so if you need a reference to the current cell, use `indirect(cell("address"))`. See the documentation: http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/cell.php

Answer (score 0):

Reference to a cell that include this formula (self reference):
**address(row();column())**

E.g. getting the value of the cell above:
**indirect(address(row()-1;column()))**

Or what the OP asked:
**=Cell(width;address(row();column()))**