# How to refer to a worksheet named range?

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a way to refer to a **worksheet named range** without activating the sheet?

I have various sheets with ranges of the same name, and I would like to refer to the ranges in vba. I would expect something like `Sheet2.Range("RangeName")` to work, but that only works when `Sheet2` is activated.

The only other way I can think of is through `Range(Sheet2.Name & "!" & "RangeName")`, but that only seems to work when `Sheet2.Name` doesn't contain spaces.

Do I need to stick to the activation of the sheets (which I like to prevent) or is there another way to refer to the range?

I am working with Excel 2016. Help is much appreciated.

Comment: Suggest recording a macro to do what you want then analyse the code generated in the macro.

Comment: I would like to read the data in the range without activate or select. Recording doesn't give me that

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel VBA: Workbook-scoped, worksheet dependent named formula/named range (result changes depending on the active worksheet)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22920090/excel-vba-workbook-scoped-worksheet-dependent-named-formula-named-range-resul)

Answer (score 0):

Enclose the sheet name in single quotes, which allows the use of spaces.

```
Range("'" & Sheet2.Name & "'!" & "RangeName")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim strSheetName As String, strrngName As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range, rngComplete As Range

    'Select sheet name
    strSheetName = "Sheet1"
    'Set sheet based on name selected above
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(strSheetName)

    'Set range name
    strSheetName = "Test"
    'Set range based on sheet name & range name
    Set rng = ws.Range(strSheetName)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit puzzled. After more testing it seems that the obvious `Sheet1.Range("RangeName")` does seem to work, even when `Sheet1` is not activated.

Thx for the answers. Sorry to have bothered you. I'll leave the question for reference