# Excel VBA > Formula not updating until workbook is saved

Tags: excel, vba

I have a very large Excel workbook (25+ worksheets, 15+ VBA modules) for financial analysis.

I've noticed that one of the formula doesn't display a value until I manually save the workbook 2 - 3 times. Before saving it will appear as a dash (-). After saving 2 - 3 times, the values appear as expected.

I have put in a few `ActiveWorkbook.Save` in my macro runs already but they don't seem to affect this case.

The formula in question is (for one cell):

```
=OFFSET(THIS_CELL, 0, -1)+INDEX('ExternalWorksheet'!$A$1:$CR$300,MATCH("Some Term",'ExternalWorksheet'!$A:$A,0),MATCH($B5,'ExternalWorksheet'!$1:$1,0))+INDEX('ExternalWorksheet'!$A$1:$CR$300,MATCH("Some Other Term",'ExternalWorksheet'!$A:$A,0),MATCH($B5,'ExternalWorksheet'!$1:$1,0))+INDEX('ExternalWorksheet'!$A$1:$CR$300,MATCH("Yet Another Term",'ExternalWorksheet'!$A:$A,0),MATCH($B5,'ExternalWorksheet'!$1:$1,0))-OFFSET(THIS_CELL, 0, -17)
```

(I know it is unruly, I didn't create it, I'm just the programmer ;) )

I am using the `THIS_CELL` trick as described [in this other SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/757413/excel-reference-to-current-cell) because this formula appears in multiple 'tables' in this worksheet.

My client isn't pleased about having this column appear as dashes and the columns that depend on it appearing as N/A until he saves. From what I can tell, this behaviour is related to the usage of THIS_CELL (or the OFFSET) as if I remove the OFFSET the cells update as expected. However, I can't see how to get rid of it as I have to repeat this formula over multiple 'tables' in the worksheet and have them reference the correct cells. I also can't switch to RC notation as my client doesn't like it.

Comment: Since `OFFSET` is a *volatile* function, that should be re-calculating on *every* calculation cycle, not just ones that affect its outcome. Is 'ExternalWorksheet' the name of a local worksheet or a worksheet in an external workbook? If it is local and pulling values from a closed external workbook, look into Excel Options ► Advanced ► When calculating this workbook ► Update links to other documents and Save external link values.

Comment: 'ExternalWorksheet' refers to a worksheet in a different workbook. I already have both Update links and Save external link turned on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a comparsion between CTRL+S save and a `ActiveWorkbook.Save` and in this case they do work differently. No matter how many times I save via VBA it wouldn't update the formulae. CTRL+S appears to be forcing a re-calculation.

From this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154434/how-do-you-get-excel-to-refresh-data-on-sheet-from-within-vba) I added in

```
ActiveSheet.EnableCalculation = False  
ActiveSheet.EnableCalculation = True
```

prior to saving and that has solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify THIS_CELL trickery to remove dependency on the `OFFSET` function altogether by changing the initial selected cell to produce the offset necessary. The reason that the first step in those directions states *select cell A1 (this is important!)* is so THIS_CELL always refers to the cell you selected. You don't want the cell that you selected. You want the one either 1 or 17 columns to the left.

(stolen and modified from [Create a named formula called THIS_CELL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/757413/excel-reference-to-current-cell))

1. In the current worksheet, select cell **R1** (this is important!)
2. Open Name Manager (Ctl+F3)
3. Click New...
4. Enter "THE_CELL_BEHIND_ME" into Name:
5. Enter the following formula into Refers to: `=!Q1`

NOTE: Be sure cell **R1** is selected. This formula is relative to the ActiveCell.

6. Under Scope: select Workbook.
7. Click OK.
8. Repeat using the name THE_CELL_WAY_BEHIND_ME and `=!A1` for refers to.
9. Close the Name Manager.

Using `=THE_CELL_BEHIND_ME` is the same as `=OFFSET(THIS_CELL, 0, -1)` and `=THE_CELL_WAY_BEHIND_ME` is the same as `=OFFSET(THIS_CELL, 0, -17)`.

Comment: While that worked to remove the OFFSET it didn't solve the problem of the value not appearing until multiple manual saves have occurred. Thank you though, I understand the THIS_CELL magic better now!