# Evaluate a relative reference from VBA relative to a known cell

Tags: vba, excel

I'm using the trick described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22264393/847721) - `!A1` - to get the the range of cells up to and including the current one (typically for a Rows() function). This works great for day to day usage, and eliminates a lot of errors that I get when moving ranges around when I previously had to use an adjacent set of rows.

Unfortunately, my formulas need to be evaluatable from VBA. With `__THISCELL__` as my `!A1` cell, and the cell housing the formula as `$Z$100` the following evaluates to an error:

```
Application.Evaluate(rngCell.formula)
```

And the following evaluates to `$A$1:$Z$50`

```
rngCell.Worksheet.Evaluate(rngCell.formula)
```

Obviously an approach is to replace `__THISCELL__` with `rngCell.Address(External:=True)` prior to evaluation, but here's the kicker: I'd like to be able to execute my formula parser in a workbook which uses, say `THIS_CELL`, `THISCELL` or `__THISCELL` safely, and I'd also like to be able to safely execute my code in a workbook with a name like `__NOT__THIS_CELL__`.

All I need for this is a mechanism to evaluate relative references relative to a specific cell address - which since people do use R1C1 references in VBA a fair bit, I imagine must be around. However, I don't know it. Can anyone help?

NB: I like to avoid fiddling with `ActiveCell`, `Selection`, etc. where possible, since those smell like the excel equivalent of `SendKeys` - who knows what the user is doing when you access them. Even then, though, I'm not certain I'll get the right answer, because for the `Worksheet.Evaluate` approach, I'm not positioned in cell $A$1!

Comment: AFAIK `Evaluate` always resolves relative named ranges with respect to `A1`, so you won't be able to calculate correct values for other cells. Why do you need to manually parse formulas?

Comment: We use `CUBEVALUE` a lot, and I need to be able to extract nfrom an arbitrary formula the MDX passed to generate the constituent `CUBEMEMBERS` and `CUBESET`s that we pass in to execute the query. `CUBEMEMBERS` aren't too evil - there is an `.mdx` property that shows the member by index (though e.g. if you get there by `FILTER()` then that gets lost), but `CUBESET`s don't have a working `.mdx` property, so need to find the argument that was passed to the function. Which since it could be found via any number of `INDEX`, `VLOOKUP` or named range process, basically means formula parsing!

Comment: Could please provide a more detailed sample of what you have done, and the expected results. Also explain what is the difference between `THIS_CELL`, `THISCELL`, `__THISCELL` and `__NOT__THIS_CELL__`. It's correct to assume that `rngCell` refers to a name equivalent to `THIS_CELL`  as described in the question referred at the beginning?

Comment: Well, the idea is that a user could define any name that had the content of `!A1` (or `!RC`). Those names are just a number of names that they could use. They could just as easily define it as `Scotland`, `Dragons` or `FooBar`, and I wouldn't want my code to break on it!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, I believe you're looking for the `Range().Offset` method.

`Range().Offset(rOffset, cOffset)` refers to a range that is `rOffset` lower and `cOffset` to the right of the given range (negative values for up and left are allowed). Also, `.Offset` can access and set all of the properties of the range, just like you would do with `.Range`.

Comment: I'm afraid not - that will let me go from one range a specified distance via X and Y to another. What I'd like to do is take some text that constitutes a formula and evaluate it as though it were entered in a known cell. To see the issue, put the cursor in, say, `A1` and create a new named range. In the refers to box, enter `=$B1`. Now in cells `A1:A5` enter your name, and put some stuff in column B. Note how even though the formulae are the same, they always refer to the cell to their right? Now, I know I'm working with a formula from `A5`, but Excel doesn't! The problem is how to tell it!

Comment: @tobriand this do not always refers to the right, it always refers to column `B`

Comment: @EEM - might be I'm using `Worksheet.Evaluate` instead of `Application.Evaluate`. I'll check my code and let you know.

Answer (score -1):

The approach I've taken for the time being is implicit in the question: when a named range is detected, store the current selection and worksheet, select the one which we use as the evaluation context, and then use Evaluate. This *seems* to work, provided the cell being evaluated is inside the activesheet.

I don't like jumping the selection all over the place - feels dirty - but short of a more elegant solution, it does work.

Comment: With the worksheet configured as you described in your comment below other answer, `Evaluate` always returns `B1` value, no matter which worksheet or cell is currently active (at least in 2010). And `rngCell.Worksheet.Evaluate(rngCell.formula)` should give the same result as `Application.Evaluate(...` for active sheet.

Comment: Hmm... well, it's definitely working for me, so I'll check again exactly what I've done. I might be using `Worksheet.Evaluate` instead of `Application.Evaluate`, which sometimes does a better job of dealing with relative ranges with respect to the current worksheet.

Comment: `Application.Evaluate` is an equivalent of `Activesheet.Evaluate`

Comment: No, not quite. They're definitely similar, but if you create a UDF with a breakpoint and pass it to `Application.Evaluate`, it gets called twice, whereas `Worksheet.Evaluate` only gets called once. There's a nice post on the issue, focusing on efficiency of the statement at https://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2011/11/02/evaluate-functions-and-formulas-fun-how-to-make-excels-evaluate-method-twice-as-fast/. I'm certain there's also differences in how they treat names, but can't remember the details.