# Is there a formula that inputs on nth row of column A by reading what's in column F and/or D on their congruent rows?

Tags: excel, if-statement, row, excel-2007, multiple-columns

I'm very new to excel programming. Currently I'm working on an excel worksheet and I need a formula that inputs on nth row of column A by reading what's in column F and/or D on their congruent rows. So far I have something like:

```
=IF(AND(D:ROW(n)=0,F:ROW(n)="x"),A:ROW(n)="e",IF(D:ROW(n)=0,"N","X"))
e.g.
  A B C D E F
1 e     0   x
2 N     0
3 X     2
```

Comment: you can find some informations here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25291631/5384879

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in A1:

```
=IF(D1 = 0,IF(F1="x","e","N"),"X")
```

And copy down.

The references are Relative, so as the formula is copy/dragged down they will change on their own.

[image]

Comment: My final version of this is

    =IF(ISBLANK($D1)," ",IF($D1 = 0,IF($F1="x","e","N"),"X"))