# Excel column number from column name

Tags: vba, excel

How to get the column number from column name in Excel using Excel macro?

Comment: have a look a this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/22708/390819 There's a VBA solution there too

Comment: Column name as in letter or as in header?

Comment: @wolf: That is the reverse of what OP wants :)

Comment: I know you asked for a macro, and you have an excellent answer, but as a side-note, in Excel you can use `=COLUMN(INDIRECT("C"&1))`. There may be an easier way..

Answer (score 175, accepted):

I think you want this?

**Column Name to Column Number**

```
Sub Sample()
    ColName = "C"
    Debug.Print Range(ColName & 1).Column
End Sub
```

**Edit**: Also including the reverse of what you want

**Column Number to Column Name**

```
Sub Sample()
    ColNo = 3
    Debug.Print Split(Cells(, ColNo).Address, "$")(1)
End Sub
```

**FOLLOW UP**

> > > Like if i have salary field at the very top lets say at cell C(1,1) now if i alter the file and shift salary column to some other place say F(1,1) then i will have to modify the code so i want the code to check for Salary and find the column number and then do rest of the operations according to that column number.

In such a case I would recommend using `.FIND` See this example below

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim strSearch As String
    Dim aCell As Range

    strSearch = "Salary"

    Set aCell = Sheet1.Rows(1).Find(What:=strSearch, LookIn:=xlValues, _
    LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

    If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Value Found in Cell " & aCell.Address & _
        " and the Cell Column Number is " & aCell.Column
    End If
End Sub
```

SNAPSHOT

[image]

Comment: like if i have salary field at the very top lets say at cell C(1,1) now if i alter the file and shift salary column to some other place say F(1,1) then i will have to modify the code so i want the code to check for Salary and find the column number and then do rest of the operations according to that column number.

Comment: If this answer satisfies your problem please be sure to select it as the best!

Comment: If I have invalid clumn name like "SUJA" I just want to know the column doesn't exist.How can we achieve this? Thanks in advance

Comment: @KaviSuja: I am not sure I understand your question

Comment: @SiddharthRout I have found solution and my actual question in following link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46660109/check-a-column-is-valid-in-excel-vb-macro/46661555#46661555

Comment: Does this fail if there are spaces in your column names? Debug.Print Range(ColName & 1).Column

Comment: @DavidMays Yes. `Range("AB" & 1).Column` will work but `Range("A b" & 1).Column` will not

Answer (score 4):

While you were looking for a VBA solution, this was my top result on google when looking for a formula solution, so I'll add this for anyone who came here for that like I did:

Excel formula to return the **number from a column letter** (From @A. Klomp's comment above), where cell A1 holds your column letter(s):

> =column(indirect(A1&"1"))

As the indirect function is volatile, it recalculates whenever any cell is changed, so if you have a lot of these it could slow down your workbook. Consider another solution, such as the 'code' function, which gives you the number for an ASCII character, starting with 'A' at 65. Note that to do this you would need to check how many digits are in the column name, and alter the result depending on 'A', 'BB', or 'CCC'.

Excel formula to return the **column letter from a number** (From this previous question [How to convert a column number (eg. 127) into an excel column (eg. AA)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/181596/how-to-convert-a-column-number-eg-127-into-an-excel-column-eg-aa), answered by @Ian), where A1 holds your column number:

> =substitute(address(1,A1,4),"1","")

Note that both of these methods work regardless of how many letters are in the column name.

Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: @ExcelHero You're missing the point of the above - in my solutions, the cell A1 *contains* the column Letter / Number. Your solution hardcodes the solution to convert "A" to 1, or 1 to "A". My version simply shows how to do this dynamically (although if you want to hardcode, yes that's possible too). Please go in and actually try these yourself, as I have confirmed that they work.

Answer (score 2):

You could skip all this and just put your data in a table. Then refer to the table and header and it will be completely dynamic. I know this is from 3 years ago but someone may still find this useful.

Example code:

```
Activesheet.Range("TableName[ColumnName]").Copy
```

You can also use :

```
activesheet.listobjects("TableName[ColumnName]").Copy
```

You can even use this reference system in worksheet formulas as well. Its very dynamic.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Here's a pure VBA solution because Excel can hold joined cells:

```
Public Function GetIndexForColumn(Column As String) As Long
    Dim astrColumn()    As String
    Dim Result          As Long
    Dim i               As Integer
    Dim n               As Integer

    Column = UCase(Column)
    ReDim astrColumn(Len(Column) - 1)
    For i = 0 To (Len(Column) - 1)
        astrColumn(i) = Mid(Column, (i + 1), 1)
    Next
    n = 1
    For i = UBound(astrColumn) To 0 Step -1
        Result = (Result + ((Asc(astrColumn(i)) - 64) * n))
        n = (n * 26)
    Next
    GetIndexForColumn = Result
End Function
```

Basically, this function does the same as any Hex to Dec function, except that it only takes alphabetical chars (A = 1, B = 2, ...).
The rightmost char counts single, each char to the left counts 26 times the char right to it (which makes AA = 27 [1 + 26], AAA = 703 [1 + 26 + 676]).
The use of UCase() makes this function case-insensitive.

Answer (score 1):

Write and run the following code in the Immediate Window

```
?cells(,"type the column name here").column
```

For example `?cells(,"BYL").column` will return 2014. The code is case-insensitive, hence you may write `?cells(,"byl").column` and the output will still be the same.

Answer (score 1):

Based on Anastasiya's answer. I think this is the shortest vba command:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim sColumnLetter as String
    Dim iColumnNumber as Integer

    sColumnLetter = "C"
    iColumnNumber = Columns(sColumnLetter).Column

    MsgBox "The column number is " & iColumnNumber
End Sub
```

Caveat: The only condition for this code to work is that a worksheet is active, because `Columns` is equivalent to `ActiveSheet.Columns`. ;)

Answer (score -4):

In my opinion the simpliest way to get column number is:
`Sub Sample()
    ColName = ActiveCell.Column
    MsgBox ColName
End Sub`