# How to copy and paste Excel sheet by option of drop downlist

Tags: excel, visual-studio, ms-access

I have an Excel workbook(s) that have worksheets with formulas for similar products. In the form I created on the worksheets, there is 2 drop down list that work together. (C2) "style" (D3) "version"  drop down used for less type-o errors when putting in entries.

What I am wanting to do is, from the selected drop down entries picked, to select worksheet "section A1: J13" and copy to a new sheet for printing and saving. There can be 3 that fit on page.

Currently filling on each sheet and copy and pasting to new new one to print. Resources I have available... Excel 2017, Access 2017, and VB 6.0.

I found [How to copy rows of from one sheet to another sheet using vbscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13747468/how-to-copy-rows-of-from-one-sheet-to-another-sheet-using-vbscript) which was helpful. But not there yet. Attached screen shot of control sheet, list, output. The yellow spots calculate the info on sheet. Can't upload picture not enough rep points..