# Converting column letter to number

Tags: excel, vba

I found code to convert number to column letter.

How can I convert from column letter to number?

```
Sub colLtr()
Dim mycolumn
mycolumn = 1000
Mcl = Left(Cells(1, mycolumn).Address(1, 0), InStr(1, Cells(1, mycolumn).Address(1, 0), "$") - 1)
MsgBox Mcl
End Sub
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Excel column number from column name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10106465/excel-column-number-from-column-name) See my answer in that post. I have shown how to do both.

Comment: That's the inverse of what OP is asking about.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can reference columns by their letter like this:

```
Columns("A")
```

So to get the column number, just modify the above code like this:

```
Columns("A").Column
```

The above line returns an integer (1 in this case).

So if you were using the variable `mycolumn` to store and reference column numbers, you could set the value this way:

```
mycolumn = Sheets("Sheet1").Columns("A").Column
```

And then you could reference your variable this way:

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Columns(mycolumn)
```

or to reference a cell (`A1`):

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1,mycolumn)
```

or to reference a range of cells (`A1:A10`)you could use:

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(1,mycolumn),Cells(10,mycolumn))
```

Comment: I've rewrite code as this                                         Sub LtrCol()
Dim AlphaColumn As String
Dim ColumnNumber As Long
AlphaColumn = "AAA"
ColumnNumber = Columns(AlphaColumn).Column
MsgBox ColumnNumber
End Sub

Comment: Seems more intuitive than the [`.range` way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10107264/1705829)

Comment: Minor point, use `.cells` instead of `cells`. Note the `.`.

Comment: Columns("A").Column gives me "object doesn't support this property or method"?

Comment: @DavidMays paste `?Columns("A").Column` in the immediate window, hit enter, and you should get the output `1`

Answer (score 4):

The answer given may be simple but it is massively sub-optimal, because it requires getting a Range and querying a property. An optimal solution would be as follows:

```
Function getColIndex(sColRef As String) As Long
  Dim sum As Long, iRefLen As Long
  sum = 0: iRefLen = Len(sColRef)
  For i = iRefLen To 1 Step -1
    sum = sum + Base26(Mid(sColRef, i)) * 26 ^ (iRefLen - i)
  Next
  getColIndex = sum
End Function

Private Function Base26(sLetter As String) As Long
  Base26 = Asc(UCase(sLetter)) - 64
End Function
```

Some examples:

```
getColIndex("A")   '-->1
getColIndex("Z")   '-->26
getColIndex("AA")  '-->27
getColIndex("AZ")  '-->52
getColIndex("AAA") '-->703
```

Answer (score 1):

To see the numerical equivalent of a letter-designated column:

```
Sub dural()
    ltrs = "ABC"
    MsgBox Cells(1, ltrs).Column
End Sub
```

Comment: Why would you reply to the question when it is already a duplicate :)?

Comment: - 1 I didn't want to downvote your post especially even after you posted an almost exact solution which I did in the duplicate thread but you outright ignored my comment.

Answer (score 0):

###### My Comments

ARich gives a good solution and shows the method I used for a while but Sancarn is right, its not optimal. It's a little slower, will cause errors if the wrong input is given, and is not very robust. Sancarn is on the right track, but lacks a little error checking: for example, getColIndex("_") and getColIndex("AE"), will both return 31. Other non-letter characters (ex: "*") sometimes return various negative values.

###### Working Function

Here is a function I wrote that will convert a column letter into a number. If the input is not a column on the worksheet, it will return -1 (unless AllowOverflow is set to TRUE).

```
Function ColLetter2Num(ColumnLetter As String, Optional AllowOverflow As Boolean) As Double
'Converts a column letter to a number (ex: C to 3, A to 1, etc). Returns -1 if its invalid.
' @ColumnLetter - the letter(s) to convert to a number.
' @AllowOverflow - if TRUE, can return a number greater than the max columns.
    On Error GoTo invalidCol
    If Len(ColumnLetter) = 0 Then GoTo invalidCol
    Dim thisChar As String
    For i = 1 To Len(ColumnLetter) 'for each character in input
        thisChar = Mid(ColumnLetter, i, 1) 'get next character
        If Asc(UCase(thisChar)) >= 65 And Asc(UCase(thisChar)) <= 90 Then 'if the character is a letter
            ColLetter2Num = ColLetter2Num + (26 ^ (Len(ColumnLetter) - i)) * (Asc(UCase(thisChar)) - 64) 'add its value to the return
        Else
            GoTo invalidCol 'if the character is not a letter, return an error
        End If
        If AllowOverflow = False And (ColLetter2Num = 0 Or ColLetter2Num > Columns.Count) Then
        'if the value is not inside the bounds of the sheet, return an error and stop
invalidCol:
            ColLetter2Num = -1 'error
            Exit Function 'stop checking
        End If
    Next i
End Function
```

###### Examples

```
 Sub test()
        Debug.Print ColLetter2Num("A") 'returns 1
        Debug.Print ColLetter2Num("IV") 'returns 256        (max columns for excel 2003 and prior))
        Debug.Print ColLetter2Num("XFD") 'returns -1        (invalid because IV is the last column for .xls workbooks)
        Debug.Print ColLetter2Num("XFD", True) 'returns 16384 (does not return -1 because AllowOverflow = TRUE)
        Debug.Print ColLetter2Num("A_", True) 'returns -1   (invalid because "_" is not a column)
        Debug.Print ColLetter2Num("132", True) 'returns -1  (invalid because "1" is not a column)
        
        If ColLetter2Num("A") <> -1 Then
            Debug.Print "The input is a valid column on the sheet."
        Else
            Debug.Print "The input is NOT a valid column on the sheet."
        End If
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If needed to write a robust function, just be carefull not to use worksheet properties (like @Zac's below) as it it will crash if active sheet is not a Worksheet, eg. a Chart