# Copy data up to last used column with vba

Tags: excel, vba

I was successfully able to copy data up to the last used row using VBA. I am trying to do the same thing but copy data from A1 to LastColumn2. Here is the code I have put together thus far:

```
Sheets("Results").Select
LastColumn = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Range("A1:" & LastColumn & "2").Select
Selection.Copy
```

The debugger highlights the third line. This is just a portion of the code - All of the variables have been dimensioned properly.

Comment: Not for an `Accept` but was my post too difficult to understand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the range you are passing is wrong because it is wating simething like:

```
Range("A1:C2").Select
```

and you are passing:

```
Range("A1:32").Select
```

So what you can do is:

```
Range(cells(1,1),cells(2,lastcolumn)).Select
```

Cell(1,1) = A1 beacuse its is row number 1 column number 1

As mentioned it is better if you just

```
Range(cells(1,1),cells(lastcolumn,2)).copy
```

Hope it helps

Comment: [INTERESTING READ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/excel-macro-avoiding-using-select)

Comment: Thanks! though I believe you meant Range(cells(1,1),cells(2,lastcolumn)).select

Answer (score 3):

You are getting the error because `LastColumn` is  number. You want the string equivalent of it i.e the column name. [**For Further Reading**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10106465/excel-column-number-from-column-name/10107264#10107264)

Avoid the use of `.Select` and fully qualify your objects. [INTERESTING READ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/excel-macro-avoiding-using-select)

Is this what you are trying?

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim LastCol As Long
    Dim LastColumn As String

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Results")

    With ws
        LastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

        '~~> Return column name from number
        LastColumn = Split(.Cells(, LastCol).Address, "$")(1)

        Set rng = .Range("A1:" & LastColumn & "2")

        Debug.Print rng.Address

        rng.Copy
    End With
End Sub
```