# Method 'Cells' of Object'_Global' failed VBA

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

EDIT: i have an access application in which i need to open an existing excel sheet, find a date (already in the sheet) and populate a row (with the date cell column) with either 1 or 0

this means i have to convert the datecell.column to the alphabet equivalent before i can set a cell to be populated.

I used a function, which i have used in excel before (as seen below)  END EDIT

```
Function Col_Letter(lngcol) As String
    Dim vArr
    vArr = Split(Cells(1, lngcol).Address(True, False), "$")
    Col_Letter = vArr(0)
    End Function
```

the code below is an example of how i use the code in my application

```
Dim  CD, d, f, f1, f2, g, strd
  ...
            For n = 0 To 10
            d = CD + n
            strd = Str(d)
            Select Case Weekday(strd)
            Case vbSunday, vbSaturday

            Case Else
            Set f = book.Worksheets(a).Range("5:5").Find(strd)
            f1 = f.Column
            f2 = Col_Letter(f1)
            g = f2 & Srow
            book.Worksheets(a).Range(g).Value = "0"
            End Select
            Next n
        End If
'CD = Current date, a = worksheetname set eariler in code, srow = excel row number set earlier in code`enter code here`
'this is executed in an excel sheet which was opened from access
```

when i run this, sometimes it runs perfectly and other times i get the Method 'Cells' of Object'_Global' failed error code and when i click debug it highlights the third line of the col_letter function

```
vArr = Split(Cells(1, lngcol).Address(True, False), "$")
```

do you have a clue to why it (seemingly) randomly chooses to display this error?

Answer (score 1):

You need to fully qualify the cells object. Try this

```
Function Col_Letter(lngcol As Integer) As String
    Col_Letter = Split(book.Sheets(1).Cells(, lngcol).Address, "$")(1)
End Function
```

or

```
Function Col_Letter(lngcol As Integer) As String
    Col_Letter = Split(book.ActiveSheet.Cells(, lngcol).Address, "$")(1)
End Function
```

The other error you may get is because of this line

```
f1 = f.Column
```

What if the find is not able to return anything? You may want to use

```
If Not f is Nothing then
    'Rest of the code
End If
```

Comment: ok thanks. the worksheet names are variables which are gotten in one of the steps in the subroutin which is why i couldnt use it in the function (thats for your first suggestion)

Comment: i used your 2nd suggestion and ran the code twice. it worked the first time and gave the same error the second time. i did "Set f = book.Worksheets(a).Range("5:5").Find(strd)
            If Not f Is Nothing Then
            f1 = f.Column
            f2 = Col_Letter(f1)
            g = f2 & Srow
            End If
        
        book.Worksheets(a).Range(g).Value = "0"  "

Comment: @user3041384: You need to understand what the function does. It splits the cells for example `$A$1` to get the Column Number. So it really doesn't matter if you don't supply a sheet name. Every workbook has minimum 1 sheet and hence we use `Sheets(1)` Regarding your 2nd comment, what error did you get and on what line?

Comment: @user3041384: By the way you can use `Split(Thisworkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(, lngcol).Address, "$")(1)` as well as shown [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10106465/excel-column-number-from-column-name/10107264#10107264)

Comment: tried your first suggestion and got Method 'ThisWorkbook' of Object'_Global' failed

Comment: @user3041384: that is strange as it works for me. What is the value of `lngcol`?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47173/discussion-between-siddharth-rout-and-user3041384)

Comment: ok so basically the codes are written in access and then there's a code that opens excel and (Set book = app.Workbooks.Add("D:\Updated\...timesheeteng.xlsm") ) and i work on the excel from access using book.worksheet(a)... etc. maybe thats why your first suggetin didnt work? <br> for the second suggetion i got the same method cells of object global failed

Comment: @user3041384: Ah! In that case replace `ThisWorkbook` with `book` :)

Answer (score 0):

so just incase you've come to this page with a similar problem here's how i fixed it.

@Siddarth pointed out my main problem was that i wasnt refering to the cells properly (explicitly) and this is a major problem since i am calling the function (which would work on an Excel sheet) from Access.

still after i tried various ways of qualifying the cell, code still wouldnt work properly therefore i decided to use another function for changing column number to letter...
i used

```
Function ColumnLetter(ColumnNumber) As String
    Dim n As Integer
    Dim c As Byte
    Dim s As String

n = ColumnNumber
Do
    c = ((n - 1) Mod 26)
    s = Chr(c + 65) & s
    n = (n - c) \ 26
Loop While n > 0
ColumnLetter = s
End Function
```

and since it doesnt require any cells from excel it works fine here...

i feel it makes the code execute a bit slower (that could just be my system) so if you still have suggestions feel free to post an answer.