# ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(x,y), Cells(w, z)).Select not working

Tags: vba, excel

Could anyone tell me why when I refer to a particular range it works fine:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("A1:D3").Select
```

but

```
ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(3, 4)).Select
```

not working?

Comment: What do you mean by not working? You get an error?

Comment: Does your actual code use a different sheet than `ActiveSheet`?

Comment: If your `ActiveSheet` is a chart, it will fail (but so will the first line also).  Can't imagine any other reason.  Most people get messed up here using `Cells` without a sheet qualifier to access cells on another sheet.  You're using the `ActiveSheet` so that issue is removed.

Comment: @Byron Unless its a simplification to post the question, and there is another worksheet involved.

Comment: This has been asked and answered so many times before in Stackoverflow. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21678304/method-cells-of-object-global-failed-vba) is one such quesiton.

Comment: Another [one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18962890/2-ways-for-clearcontents-on-vba-excel-but-1-work-fine-why) Question is different but addresses the same issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect your code is in the worksheet code module of a different sheet, so the unqualified `Cells` calls refer to *that* sheet, not the active one. You should **always** qualify **all** `Range` or `Cells` calls with a `Worksheet` object:

```
ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1), ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 4)).Select
```

This also works avoiding the need to repeat several times the target worksheet: 
(see https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/gg264723.aspx)

```
With ActiveSheet
    .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(3, 4)).Select
End With
```