# Copy a variable Range from one sheer to another in VBA

Tags: excel, range, copy-paste, vba

I am trying to estimate the range of a table in an excel spreasheet and then copy it from one sheet to another. I have succcessfully estimated the LastRow and LastColumn of the table using the below code.

```
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    'Ctrl + Shift + End
    LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    LastColumn = sht.Cells(7, sht.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
```

How do I copy this range now and paste it to another sheet ? The starting cell is also an input stored as a string.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (Untested)

```
sht.Range("A1:" & Split(sht.Cells(, LastColumn).Address, "$")(1) & LastRow).Copy <Dest>
```

`<Dest>` could be something like `Sheet2.Range("A1")`

To understand what `Split(sht.Cells(, LastColumn).Address, "$")(1)` does, see the section [Column Number to Column Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10106465/excel-column-number-from-column-name/10107264#10107264)

Comment: I tired this but I am getting the error Application defined or object defined error.

Comment: This is my code - sht.Range("A1:" & Split(sht.Cells(, LastColumn).Address, "$")(1) & LastRow).Copy (sht2.Range("A1"))

Comment: Have you defined `Sht2`?

Comment: yes - Dim sht2 As Worksheet
    Set sht2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

Comment: Ah I see your mistake... Remove the extra brackets... try this `sht.Range("A1:" & Split(sht.Cells(, LastColumn).Address, "$")(1) & LastRow).Copy sht2.Range("A1")`

Comment: Great ! Thank you so much :)