# How to use column letters in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm currently struggling with the following problem

I'm trying to implement an input box where a user can input the character of the column.

After that, i dont know how to convert this into a number to use it in the `Worksheet.Cells` Method

*For example*: The User inputs "B", so the program saves it in a variable named x and converts it into a number so it can be used as `Worksheet.Cells(Row, X)`

Is there any method or does someone has an idea how to do this?

Comment: You can say column("b:b").column or use"b" in range or cells sa range("b" & row)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel column number from column name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10106465/excel-column-number-from-column-name)

Comment: `Worksheet.Cells(Row, X)` will work whether `X` is a letter or number.

Comment: Why can't you use `Range(X&":"&X)` instead of `Cells()`?

Answer (score 8):

Cells() is your friend.

Don't overthink this.

```
Cells(1, 1) = "jello" ' changes cell A1
Cells(2, "AZ") = "too much jello" ' changes cell AZ2
```

The second argument of Cells() can be either a number or the alpha column header.

Answer (score 0):

B is the second column, so you can use the expression (based on ASCII):

```
Sub main()
    Dim s As String
    s = "AB"
    example s
End Sub

Sub example(s As String)

    Dim colNum As Integer
    Dim i As Integer

    i = 1: colNum = 0
    While (Mid(s, i, 1) <> "")
        colNum = colNum * 26 + (Asc(UCase(Mid(s, i, 1))) - Asc("A") + 1)
        i = i + 1
    Wend
    MsgBox colNum
End Sub
```

Comment: I was about to suggest this myself, but a problem occurs once you move past column Z: `?Asc(lcase("aa"))-asc("a")+1` in the immediate-window outputs 1.

Answer (score 0):

```
Function getColNum(colLetter As String) As Long
    On Error Resume Next   'will return 0 if letter > last col
    getColNum = Range(colLetter & "1").Column
End Function
```