# How to check if a string is a valid column name?

Tags: excel, vba

I have column names (A,B,C,AB,AC,,,,) stored in string variable.

My requirment is to get column number. Before that, I want to check the given column name is valid. For example `AD,AC,DF,ER,FC,KL` are valid where `World,kavisuja` are invalid.

If I have valid column name I can get by following code:

```
Range(ColumnChar & 1).Column
```

Comment: Check that the character string is either (1 character) or (2 characters) or (3 characters and < "XFE")

Comment: What version of excel are you using? You can use regular expressions (string is equal or less than 3 characters that belong to [A-Z] range). If first character is "X" then second must be "F" or less, third character musn't exceed "D"

Comment: @YowE3K here why we check (3 characters and < "XFE"),  XEF is the last column or any other reason

Comment: You seem to be going to a lot of trouble when you could just assign your range to a variable and see whether it worked?  (E.g. `On Error Resume Next` `Set rng = Nothing` `Set rng = Range(your_range_string)` `On Error GoTo 0` `If rng Is Nothing Then` `some sort of error processing` `Else` `some sort of processing` `End If`

Comment: `"XFD"` is the last column in current worksheets.  So `"XFD" < "XFE"` is `True` but something like `"ZAB" < "XFE"` is `False`.  (P.S. You could even test `Len(ColumnChar) < 4 And Right("AA" & ColumnChar, 3) < "XFE"` and then not have to worry about doing different things for one and two character strings.)

Comment: @YowE3K Thank you, its working

Answer (score 2):

This is how I would have done it, pretty similar to the idea of @YowE3K in the comments:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TestMe()

    Debug.Print isValid("ZZZ")    'False
    Debug.Print isValid("ZZ")     'True
    Debug.Print isValid("ABCD")   'False

End Sub

Public Function isValid(strInput As String) As Boolean

    On Error GoTo isValid_Error

    Dim rngSet  As Range
    Set rngSet = Range(strInput & "1")
    isValid = True

    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Function

isValid_Error:
End Function
```

The default value of the function is `False`, thus if it is not set to `True` it gives `False` by default.

Answer (score 1):

```
Private Sub Test()
    Dim ColumnChar As String
    ColumnChar = "AD"

    If IsColumnName(ColumnChar) Then
        Debug.Print Columns(ColumnChar).Column
    End If
End Sub

' Returns True if valid column name, otherwise False
Public Function IsColumnName(strInput As String) As Boolean
    If strInput Like WorksheetFunction.Rept("[a-zA-Z]", Len(strInput)) Then
        If Evaluate("IsRef(" & strInput & "1)") Then IsColumnName = True
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: While your code may solve the problem, having a description about why your solution works would be very beneficial.