# Convert column letter to number

Tags: excel, vba

I get raw data from querys into Excel, and when preforming VLOOKUP's sometimes I have to count or calculate by hand what column I am going to refer to.

I want a calculator were I type in userform textbox ex: "M", and the other textbox will show the correct column number for "M" (13).

My userform looks like this:

[image]

I have come up with something like the code below, I dim every letter as an integer and when that is typed in to the textbox it will add each others values.

I don't know how to code the CommandButton1_click "Räkna".

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    'how do i transform letters into numbers here?

End Sub

Sub raknare()

Dim a As Integer
Dim b As Integer
Dim c As Integer
Dim d As Integer
Dim e As Integer
Dim f As Integer
Dim g As Integer
Dim h As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim k As Integer
Dim l As Integer
Dim m As Integer
Dim n As Integer
Dim o As Integer
Dim p As Integer
Dim q As Integer
Dim r As Integer
Dim s As Integer
Dim t As Integer
Dim u As Integer
Dim v As Integer
Dim w As Integer
Dim x As Integer
Dim y As Integer
Dim z As Integer

Set a = 1
Set b = 2
Set c = 3
Set d = 4
Set e = 5
Set f = 6
Set g = 7
Set h = 8
Set i = 9
Set j = 10
Set k = 11
Set l = 12
Set m = 13
Set n = 14
Set o = 15
Set p = 16
Set q = 17
Set r = 18
Set s = 19
Set t = 20
Set u = 21
Set v = 22
Set w = 23
Set x = 24
Set y = 25
Set z = 26

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

To get info from a dialogue to a variable, you'd do something like

```
Dim v As Variant
v = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Letter: ", Title:="Letter", Type:=2)
If CBool(v) Then ' The inputbox returns "false" if cancel is pressed
  ...
EndIf
```

If you want to use a userform instead, you'd do something like

```
Dim s As String
s = UserForm1.TextBox1.Text
```

To get the column number from its name, you can either do something like what's described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10107264/4497791).

Or do what I've done in my office, and do the arithmetic yourself:

[image]

Comment: Haha, I love the picture and I sort of using that technique at the moment. My problem starts when i have up to BR in columns of data and have to calculate by hand and sometimes i get it wrong. I just want to simplify by adding a userform that does it all for me!

But give me a few mins and i will try your code, thanks for the answere!

Comment: @sam looking at that answer i linked may be of some help to you too.

Comment: Its not quite the code I was looking for, since i want to code this in userform textboxes.

Comment: @sam Instead of using `debug.print`, you can use e.g. `UserForm1.TextBox2 = Range(ColName & 1).Column`

Comment: @sam The main diffifculty I can think of will be validating that the contents of textbox1 will always be a valid columnname... Of course, if it is only you who will be using the tool, such validation may not be necessary.

Comment: Im not quite sure I understand exactly how you mean, I am quite new to all of this. But did you see my solution to the problem? It works as intended but its probably not the best solution haha.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem! But not the way I initially intended. I took some old code i had from a previous project and made it work on this issue to.

I made a sheet called "DATA" and inserted column A with the alphabet A to CW, and next to that i have the corresponding number for each letter 1-100.

Then i made a search function that looks like this:

```
Sub rakna()

    Dim rSearch As Range
    Dim rFound As Range

    With Sheets("DATA")
        Set rSearch = .Range("A1", .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

        Set rFound = rSearch.Find(What:=TextBox1.Text, LookIn:=xlValues)

        If rFound Is Nothing Then
            TextBox2.Value = ""
        Else
            TextBox2.Value = rFound.Offset(0, 1).Value


        End If
    End With


End Sub
```

Now I dont need to calculate the columns no more I can just type the one I need in my textbox!

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim Letter As String
    Dim LetterNumber As Long

    Letter = "F"
    LetterNumber = Range(Letter & 1).Column

End Sub
```