# Looking for a way to Autofill Using a Variable Range

Tags: excel, vba, autofill

I'm looking for a way to autofill my formula down to the last row in the dataset (which is variable) using a range which is also variable. I have highlighted my issue below at the bottom.

Here is the code that I have now:

```
Sub MissingData()
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim LastCol As Long

    Set ws = Worksheets("Insert Data")

    With ws
        Last Row = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        Last Col = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

        'Inserting Column Header next to the last column in the data set in row 1"
        .Cells(1, LastCol + 1).Value = "Header"

        'Inserting Formula next ot the last column in the data set in row 2"
        .Cells(2, LastCol + 1).Formula = "=iferror(AJ2,""YES"")"
    End With

    Dim FoundCell As Range

    'Looking for the Last Row in the Dataset"
    'Column A:A will always be populated with data and will be the driver
    'for how many rows are in the data set"
    LR = Worksheets("Insert Data").Range("A:A").End(xlDown).Row

    With ws
        'I set this and then called it using select because my range above
        'and the location of this cell could be variable"
        Set FoundCell = .Cells(2, LastCol + 1)
        FoundCell.Select

        'Here lies my issue.  Using this syntax the formula is filled all the way
        'to the last row available in Excel which is like 1 million something.
        'I just need it filled to the last now that i set above"
        Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.End(xlDown))
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: [Use `xlUp` to find the last row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-excel-with-vba).

Answer (score 2):

A better alternative to `AutoFill` is to enter the formula in the entire range in one go. Is this what you are trying?

```
Option Explicit

Sub MissingData()
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim LastCol As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim LastColName As String
    
    Set ws = Worksheets("Insert Data")

    With ws
        '~~> Find last row
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

        '~~> Find last column and add 1 to it
        LastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1

        '~~> Get Column name from column number
        ' https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10106465/excel-column-number-from-column-name
        LastColName = Split(.Cells(, LastCol).Address, "$")(1)
        
        '~~> Add header
        .Range(LastColName & 1).Value = "Header"
        
        '~~> Add the formula in the entire range in ONE GO
        ' Example: Range("D2:D" & LastRow).Formula = "=IFERROR(AJ2,""YES"")"
        .Range(LastColName & 2 & ":" & LastColName & LastRow).Formula = "=IFERROR(AJ2,""YES"")"
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Worked to perfection.  I was making it harder on my self than needed :)