# How to get range based on two variables in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a last_row and last_column variable.

I get these by doing the following.

`last_column = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column`

and

`last_row = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row`

My question is this, I'm trying to create a selection based on these variables, so that the range goes from `E33` to the last row and column. However, I am getting an error. Here is the code.

`Range("E33:" & last_column & last_row).Select`

Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Cells() with column and row numbers

```
set myRange = Range(Cells(33, "E"),Cells(last_row,last_column))
```

Unless you're using this code in a sheet module, make sure you qualify the sheet that the Range and the Cells method address.

Answer (score 2):

> Range("E33:" & last_column & last_row).Select

You need to convert the `last_column` to a string before you use it in the above code. Is this what you are trying to achieve?

```
Dim ColName As String
Dim rng As Range

ColName = Split(Cells(, last_column).Address, "$")(1)
Set rng = ws.Range("E33:" & ColName & last_row)
```

In the above code `ws` is the relevant sheet.

**NOTE**

1. Avoid the use of `.Select`. You may want to see [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)
2. [Excel column number from column name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10106465/excel-column-number-from-column-name)