# Split data by column name

Tags: excel, vba, split

Currently I have a macro running, not developed by me, which goes over tables in different sheets and splits them by the unique values of the column selected (1, 2, etc.). To select the column, it asks for an input, the column number, however, I would like to split instead by a column name (in row 1), and this column name to be inputted via a message box as well, since it can vary.

As an example, in sheet1, I have a column named "Region", so I would input "Region" on the input box, opposed to it's column number, as the code currently does.

Can anyone please advise how to make this change? My VBA experience is very limited.

Thank you.

Functioning code:

```
Sub Split_Files()
    
    Const aibPrompt As String = "Which column would you like to filter by?"
    Const aibtitle As String = "Filter Column"
    Const aibDefault As Long = 1
    
    Dim dFileExtension As String: dFileExtension = ".xlsx"
    Dim dFileFormat As XlFileFormat: dFileFormat = xlOpenXMLWorkbook
    Dim dFolderPath As String: dFolderPath = "XYZ"
    
    If Right(dFolderPath, 1) <> "\" Then dFolderPath = dFolderPath & "\"
    If Len(Dir(dFolderPath, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then Exit Sub ' folder not found
    If Left(dFileExtension, 1) <> "." Then dFileExtension = "." & dFileExtension
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim sCol As Variant
    sCol = Application.InputBox(aibPrompt, aibtitle, aibDefault, , , , , 1)
    If Len(CStr(sCol)) = 0 Then Exit Sub ' no entry
    If sCol = False Then Exit Sub ' canceled
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    If sws.FilterMode Then sws.ShowAllData
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = sws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    Dim srCount As Long: srCount = srg.Rows.Count
    If srCount < 3 Then Exit Sub ' not enough rows
    Dim srrg As Range: Set srrg = srg.Rows(1) ' to copy column widths
    Dim scrg As Range: Set scrg = srg.Columns(sCol)
    Dim scData As Variant: scData = scrg.Value
    
    ' Write the unique values from the 1st column to a dictionary.
    
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare ' case insensitive
    
    Dim Key As Variant
    Dim r As Long
    
    For r = 2 To srCount
        Key = scData(r, 1)
        If Not IsError(Key) Then ' exclude error values
            If Len(Key) > 0 Then ' exclude blanks
                dict(Key) = Empty
            End If
        End If
    Next r
    If dict.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub ' only error values and blanks
    Erase scData
    
    Dim dwb As Workbook
    Dim dws As Worksheet
    Dim dfcell As Range
    Dim dFilePath As String
    
    For Each Key In dict.Keys
        ' Add a new (destination) workbook and reference the first cell.
        Set dwb = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet) ' one worksheet
        Set dws = dwb.Worksheets(1)
        Set dfcell = dws.Range("A1")
        ' Copy/Paste
        srrg.Copy
        dfcell.PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
        srg.AutoFilter sCol, Key
        srg.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy dfcell
        sws.ShowAllData
        dfcell.Select
        ' Save/Close
        dFilePath = dFolderPath & "Access Rights Review " & Key & dFileExtension ' build the file path
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False ' overwrite without confirmation
        dwb.SaveAs dFilePath, xlOpenXMLWorkbook
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        dwb.Close SaveChanges:=False
    Next Key
    
    sws.AutoFilterMode = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    MsgBox "Data exported.", vbInformation
    
End Sub
```

Comment: One option is to use `Range.Find` or `Application.Match` to find the column header.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10106465/excel-column-number-from-column-name/10107264#10107264 ?