# How do I Use a custom function to grab data from a CSV File

Tags: excel, vba, import

This is my first attempt at custom functions in excel. I have been having troubles getting my csv file to import into an existing workbook so I thought I'd use a custom function to pull the data I need so i attempted to implement that function as a vba module:

Test file: Potter.csv (only has 2 records)

The function call I used is

```
=ImportCSVData("Potter.csv",D2,F1)
```

and

```
=ImportCSVData("Potter.csv","D2","F1")
```

Both were met with the #VALUE! error and I'm unsure how to resolve it

I created the following:

```
Function ImportCSVData(csvFilePath As String, sourceCell As String, destinationCell As String)
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim csvWb As Workbook
    Dim csvWs As Worksheet
    
    ' Get the current worksheet
    Set ws = Application.Caller.Worksheet
    
    ' Open the CSV file
    Set csvWb = Workbooks.Open(csvFilePath)
    Set csvWs = csvWb.Sheets(1)
    
    ' Get data from the source cell in CSV and put it in the destination cell
    ws.Range(destinationCell).Value = csvWs.Range(sourceCell).Value
    
    ' Close the CSV file without saving changes
    csvWb.Close False
    
    ' Release memory
    Set csvWs = Nothing
    Set csvWb = Nothing
    Set ws = Nothing
End Function
```

Here is a screenshot of the test csv file:

[image: Csv file named Potter.csv .Contains two records with the following headings: Date, time, service provider, client name, client phone, comments, service category]

I expected it to return "James Potter" in the cell I specified but instead both were met with the #VALUE! error and I'm unsure how to resolve it

Comment: `csvFilePath` probably requires the full path: ie. `"C:\Temp\Potter.csv"`

Comment: Your function should return the data, not (attempt to) write it to the cell. UDFs are meant to return a value and aren't meant to modify cells, though they can in some limited and edge cases.

Comment: https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/advantages-custom-functions-excel/#:~:text=A%20UDF%20cannot%20copy%20and,you%20should%20use%20conditional%20formatting.

Comment: This may help  ...  https://davetallett26.github.io/excel-markdown.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My assuption is you've got a comma separted text file and the lines are separated by `VBCRLF`.

This function reads the complete textfile into a string

```
Function getTextfile(ByVal fileName As String) As String
   
    Dim fileNr As Long
    fileNr = FreeFile
        
    Open fileName For Input As fileNr
    getTextfile = Input(LOF(fileNr), fileNr)
    Close fileNr

End Function
```

One can take the output of this function to split it and retrieve a certain value

```
 Function getCSVData(inpFile As String, col As String, rowNr As Long) As String

    Dim vdata As Variant
    vdata = getTextfile(inpFile)
    vdata = Split(vdata, vbCrLf)
    
    ' Be Careful here.
    ' we have 0-based arrays
    Dim inpRow As Variant
    inpRow = vdata(rowNr - 1)               'get the complete row
    
    Dim colNr As Long
    colNr = colLetter2Number(col) - 1 
    getCSVData = Split(inpRow, ",")(colNr)  'get the column 

End Function
```

The function `colLetter2Number` will just convert a letter to a column number

```
Function colLetter2Number(inpLetter As String) As Long
    ' This will work in this case because an active sheet is available
    ' Otherwise use a function which is not dependant on an active sheet
    ' https://stackoverflow.com/a/57774110/6600940
    colLetter2Number = Columns(inpLetter).Column
End Function
```

You can use `getCSVData` in a sheet as an UDF `=getCSVData("D:\TMP\data.txt","D",4)` which you should probably not do that often as it will open the text file several time when updating.

One can test it like that

```
Sub testIt()
    Dim fileName As String
    fileName = "D:\TMP\data.txt"
    Debug.Print getCSVData(fileName, "D", 4)
End Sub
```

Comment: Watch out for files where one or more values contain a comma and have been wrapped in double quotes - your parsing will break down in those cases.

Comment: Right, I know, my solution is not fool proof. But one does not need to use excel to open a CSV file for an UDF. And even with Excel you will run into pitfalls like a client phone 0049123456789.

Comment: No in most cases this is fine - just a heads-up to the OP in case they had data like that….

Answer (score 0):

This might be the only workaround for opening a file (in Excel) in a UDF:

```vb
Function GetCSVData(path, rng As String)
    Dim v, wb As Workbook, xl As Excel.Application
    Set xl = New Excel.Application
    Set wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(path, ReadOnly:=True)
    v = wb.Worksheets(1).range(rng).Value
    wb.Close False
    xl.Quit
    GetCSVData = v
End Function
```

Spinning up a new Excel instance is pretty slow though.