# Looping through column by alphabets - Excel VB

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a formula based on various cells. For that I wrote a function to get the cell reference (ex K2, M9 etc).
I'm able to get the code working for one column but I'm stuck when I need to loop through columns. I checked multiple posts and everywhere looping through column is possible using cell address and not by column alphabets. Is it possible to loop through column alphabets?

```
Function qscAddr(Sku As String, LineType As String, Customer As String, Column As String) As String
    Dim X As Long
    If IsNull(Customer) Then
        For X = 2 To Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            If Cells(X, "B").Value = Sku And Cells(X, "J").Value = LineType Then
                qscAddr = Column & X
                Exit Function
            End If
        Next
    Else
        For X = 2 To Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            If Cells(X, "B").Value = Sku And Cells(X, "J").Value = LineType And Cells(X, "I").Value = Customer Then
                qscAddr = Column & X
                Exit Function
            End If
        Next
    End If
End Function

Sub Form_Load()
    Dim c_xxx As String
    Dim c_yyy As String
    Dim c_zzz As String
    Dim Cell As Range
    
    Range("B3:B6500").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=Range("AG3"), Unique:=True
    
    For Each Cell In Range("AG4:AG28").Cells
        c_xxx = qscAddr(Cell.Value, "Current Forecast - Customer", "XXX", "K")
        c_yyy = qscAddr(Cell.Value, "Current Forecast - Customer", "YYY", "K")
        c_zzz = qscAddr(Cell.Value, "Current Forecast - Customer", "ZZZ", "K")
        Range(qscAddr(Cell.Value, "XYZ", "", "K")).Select
        Selection.Formula = "=" & c_xxx & "+" & c_yyy & "+" & c_zzz & ""
        
    Next Cell
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Does [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10106465/excel-column-number-from-column-name/10107264#10107264) put you in the right direction?

Comment: Whatabout using an array for Column, and iterate it?

Answer (score 1):

- Loop through columns with index or name

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub demo()
    Dim i As Long
    ' eg. loop through columns K to M
    For i = 11 To 13
        Debug.Print Cells(1, i).Address, Cells(1, i).Value
    Next
    
    Dim arrCol As Variant, vCol As Variant
    arrCol = Array("K", "L", "M")
    For Each vCol In arrCol
        Debug.Print Cells(1, vCol).Address, Cells(1, vCol).Value
    Next
    
    ' convert column index to name
    For i = 11 To 13
        Debug.Print "Column index: " & i, "Column name: " & Split(Cells(1, i).Address, "$")(1)
    Next
End Sub
```